# Why do I get this output in PowerShell sort -unique Count

Tags: powershell

I typed the following command to find out how many unique objects there were and it gave me 5.  I don't know why this gives 5.

```
> $var = @(2,4,2,5,3,6,34,6,3,6,4,6,3,5,5,353,5343,5,3,56,34)  
>$var | sort -Unique  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
34  
56  
353  
5343  
>$var | sort -Unique Count  
5
```

Comment: Good question! This seems like a bug to me... 5 seems to be coming from the parameter `-Property` but i'm not sure why. `-Property` seems to take any string... The number returned is just an item from the incoming list, for example `1,4,6,12,65,3,13 | Sort-Object -Unique -Property itsABugMaybe` returns `65`. You might want to post this [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell)

Comment: Thanks I posted it there as you suggested. - https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/725505/powershell-returning-invalid-number-for-this-command

Comment: I'll vote that up too.  It's definitely flakey.  If you reverse the array, it comes out 34.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$var | sort -Unique COUNT` is the same as: `$var | sort -Unique -Property COUNT`

So what sort is doing is looking for the "COUNT" property on each of the elements in the array to determine whether they are unique or not.  You can see how this works if you do the following:

```
GPS sv* | sort -Unique ID
GPS sv* | sort -Unique Name
```

Since none of the objects have a "COUNT" property, sort sees them all as the same and therefore none are unique and it is returning one of the elements.  The clue came from trying the following:

```
$var = $("a", "b", "c", "b")
$var | sort -Unique count
```

this produced the result "c".

Measure is your friend here:

```
$var |sort -Unique |measure
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: "and it is returning one of the elements", so it randomly returns a value in the list? It seems it also returns the same element if you don't add the an element in the list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm  not sure why it's doing that either, but -sort doesn't have a count parameter.

I think what you might be after is:

```
$var = @(2,4,2,5,3,6,34,6,3,6,4,6,3,5,5,353,5343,5,3,56,34)  
($var | sort -Unique).count
```

Comment: The string `"Count"` is filling in the positional for `-Property` (Position 1) which is outputting one of the items from the incoming object for some reason.

Comment: Well certainly your answer is the right way to do it.  I was trying to understand why is going behind the scenes here.  Thanks for responding.